# Why is my code returning two results instead of one

Tags: python, if-statement

I am writing a simple code for a password controller which should return false if the string contains less than 8 characters and false if the string contains 8 or more characters. but i am getting two response one is either true or false, and the other result is <function password at 0x00000272BA8B7F70>.

Here is the code I have written:

```
def password(str):
    if len(str) >= 8:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
    return password
print(password("gtbd"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The first output (`true` or `false`) is because your function is doing that when you call it, via `print("true")` or `print("false")`.

The second output is because your function returns itself:

```
return password
```

...and you print that return value (the function) when you call it:

```
print(password("gtbd"))
```

If you wanted that `print` to print the `true` or `false`, **don't** print it within the function, and return it from the function:

```
def password(str):
    return len(str) >= 8
```

Or if you want the function to return a string rather than a boolean:

```
def password(s):
    return str(len(s) >= 8)
```

*(Note that I had to change the name of your parameter.)*

If you really want it in lower case:

```
def password(s):
    return str(len(s) >= 8).lower()
```

Or of course, do it manually:

```
def password(s):
    if len(s) >= 8:
        return "true"
    return "false"
```

Comment: Hey crowder, thanks for the answer. Really appreciate it.